# How to set TotalPages of a PageImpl class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pageable

I'm converting a Page to a new one by using PageImpl class, but the totalpages attribute has the default value 0. I would like to set totalPages to a specific number. Is it possible to change it?

**code**

```
    public Page<InformationDTO> getInformationById(String classId, int page, int size) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        List<Information> InformationList = informationRepository.findByClassIdOrderByCreateDateDesc(classId, pageable).getContent();
        List<InformationDTO> InformationDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!InformationList.isEmpty()){
            for (Information information: informationList){
                informationDTOList.add(new InformationDTO(information));
            }
        }
        return new PageImpl<InformationDTO>(informationDTOList,pageable,informationList.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get a page as an answer you need to change a line in your code**

```
// Earlier
List<Information> InformationList = informationRepository.findByClassIdOrderByCreateDateDesc(classId, pageable).getContent();

// Changed line
Page<Information> InformationList = informationRepository.findByClassIdOrderByCreateDateDesc(classId, pageable);


// Then you will not be required to explicitly change into pageable
PageImpl<InformationDTO>(informationDTOList,pageable,informationList.size());
```

**Case 1**
To find maximum pages

```
InformationList.getTotalPages()
```

**Case 2 - Your scenario - From a collection object If want data with pagination then you have to take the help from PageImpl class.**

which offer 2 Constructor to do this

```
PageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total)
```

where

1. content – the content of this page(Your collection object).
2. pageable – the paging information
3. total – the total amount of items available.

There is also another constructor

```
PageImpl(List<T> content)
```

**Note - This will result in the created Page being identical to the entire List.**

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my problem. but instead of informationList.size() I used informationList.getTotalElements()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
int totalPages = InformationList.getTotalPages();
```

Comment: thanks, but what I need is to set the tolatpages not to get totalPages